# Angular Service Test. Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, eslint

According to https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#testing-http-services, I wrote the following service.spec (Angular 8):

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MyService } from "../../services/my.service";

describe('MyService', () => {

    let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy; post: jasmine.Spy };

    let service: MyService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [MyService]
        }); // this I need for another test
        httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get', 'post']);
        service = new MyService(httpClientSpy as any);
    });

    it('checkAccess returns true', () => {
        httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => true });

        service
            .checkAccess(1234)
            .subscribe((value: boolean) => // ESLint marks this...
                expect(value).toBeTruthy(), // ... and this ...
                fail                         // ... as a problem
            );
    });
}
```

The service method:

```
public checkAccess(id: number): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiUrlPart}/${id}/access`, {
        params: new InterceptorHttpParams({ showLoader: true }, {})
    });
}
```

All tests (I wrote a few with the same principle for a few service's methods) passed with success, application builds also with success.

But, my ESLint raises the problem "Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected" of the .subscribe row of the spec (1st code fragment).
I read https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md#options, I also googled and found some advices which didn't help me. For example:

```
httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncData(true)); // with asyncData helper from ng docs - see the link above
httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(of(true));
```

After that, I finally want to ask, maybe such a construction is ok for tests and thus I should just disable this rule for spec files (or configure rules like this https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md#options)?
If there is really an error that should be fixed, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What do you think `=> expect(value).toBeTruthy(), fail` does? Why don't you write an actual function body?

Comment: I didn't understand you completetly. I just followed Ng Docs example. What do u mean as 'actual function body'?

Comment: See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions - `(value: boolean) => expect(value).toBeTruthy()` is an arrow function that returns the result of the expression ("concise body", whereas if you had a function body ("block body") `(value: boolean) => { expect(value).toBeTruthy(); }` it would be an arrow function returning undefined.